# How to fix this in EM6

Tags: javascript

I know that it's a silly question, but I can't fix it.
I have this code

```
var v=function v(e){for(var r=e.toString(),a="",n=0;n<r.length&&"00"!==r.substr(n,2);n+=2){a+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(r.substr(n,2),16))}return a}
```

and I've changed to this

```
const v = function v (e) {
    for (let r = e.toString(), a = '', n = 0; n < r.length && r.substr(n, 2) !== '00'; n += 2) {
    a += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(r.substr(n, 2), 16))
  }
  return a
}
```

And the lint tells me (after e.toString(),)
let a: string
'a' is declared but its value is never read.Vetur(6133)
'a' is assigned a value but never used.
Anyone knows how to fix it??

Comment: You need to click edit and read the formatting instructions. Make use of the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: As `let` is used I don't think `a` is accessible outside the for loop block. So the `a` being returned will throw a "not defined" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` has block scope.

You are declaring `a` scoped to the loop.

Each time you go around the loop, you get a new `a`.

Then you try to return a global `a`.

```js
const a = "global";

const v = function v(e) {
  for (let r = e.toString(), a = '', n = 0; n < r.length && r.substr(n, 2) !== '00'; n += 2) {
    a += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(r.substr(n, 2), 16))
  }
  return a
}

const result = v("123456");
console.log(result);
```

Declare `a` outside the loop.

```js
const a = "global";

const v = function v(e) {
  let a = '';
  for (let r = e.toString(), n = 0; n < r.length && r.substr(n, 2) !== '00'; n += 2) {
    a += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(r.substr(n, 2), 16))
  }
  return a
}

const result = v("123456");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is scope issue. In your code, scope variable 'a' is limited to for loop and you are trying to access it outside of the for loop. So keep declare it outside either in function scope or in global scope. Check out the below code.

```
  const v = (e) => {
    let a = '';
    for (let r = e.toString(), a = '', n = 0; n < r.length && r.substr(n, 2) !== '00'; n += 2) {
      a += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(r.substr(n, 2), 16));
    }
    return a;
  }
```